# Nuxt privateRuntimeConfig access inside Plugin

Tags: vue.js, plugins, environment-variables, nuxt.js

Nuxt in 2.13 released [runtimeConfig](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/runtime-config/) and tells us to migrate from dotenv in this [article](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config)

I created a **.env** file where i wrote my variables and made sure that is ignored in my **.gitignore** file.

**In nuxt.config.js** I added the fallowing

```
privateRuntimeConfig: {
    apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
}
```

Like this I have access to my apiKey in nuxt.config.js and it works nice. However I use a [plugin](https://github.com/xon52/x5-gmaps) for google maps where I need to put my apiKey in my plugin js file I created. I'm trying something like this but I cant access to my .env variables.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import x5GMaps from 'x5-gmaps'

export default ({ app }) => { Vue.use(x5GMaps, app.context.$config.apiKey) }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
export default ({ app }) => { Vue.use(x5GMaps, app.$config.apiKey) }
```

But it just work with `publicteRuntimeConfig`

Comment: Doesn't this produce a memory leak as stated here: https://medium.com/@oliverolmaru/memory-leak-in-ssr-nuxt-js-if-everything-else-fails-1a28e6c2e360?